# Issues with running Apache on one IP

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I currently have a machine with multiple IPs, however I wish to limit Apache to just one of them.

I understand this question has been asked already here however I have run into issues following it: [Limit Apache to a single IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/415441/limit-apache-to-a-single-ip)

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have an IP, 1.1.1.1 which I want Apache to run on, meanwhile another IP, 2.2.2.2 is available to Apache however I do not want Apache to touch this IP.

In my ports.conf:

```
Listen 1.1.1.1:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 1.1.1.1:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 1.1.1.1:443
</IfModule>
```

Meanwhile, 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Using the configuration, there are no errors on startup, however when visiting 1.1.1.1 in a browser, it appears to take me no to /var/www/html (the default Apache2 page) but rather to one of my sites currently running on the IP too.

Additonally, using:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
```

Appear to allow you to visit 1.1.1.1 in browser and get /var/www/html (the default Apache2 page) yet on startup using this configuration gives the error:

```
[Tue Aug 18 17:34:54.487039 2015] [core:error] [pid 5446] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for 1.1.1.1 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
```

I am stumped by this one, if anyone could show me as to what is going wrong, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...or specify an explicit ServerName* - here's the point. You have to be missing `ServerName your.fqdn` in your configuration. Ubuntu's httpd doesn't have it by default.

Go with `<VirtualHost *:80>` version. Create */etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf*, put `ServerName your.fqdn` there, run `a2enconf servername`, then `service apache2 reload`. Remember to also set *ServerName* inside every *VirtualHost* block (may be skipped for default one).

Other than that, your IP configuration seems fine. Make sure *000-default.conf* is enabled (a link present in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled*).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, leave everything as it is and create a file called 'servername.conf' in _/etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf_ and run a2enconf servername? What should I actually put in the servername.conf file? Remember I am running multiple sites off the one IP. Sorry, I am really new to all this.

Comment: Edited the answer to make 2nd paragraph more clear. The proposed change doesn't interfere with name-based virtual hosting that you probably have configured (I assume this is what you mean by *multiple sites off the one IP*).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me solve this issue. For reference, all virtual hosts need to use _*:80_ which is what was causing the issues regarding the server serving the wrong site.